# ActionBar support libraries

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo

I am developing using API Level 8 (Froyo). This API does not provide ActionBar feature (ActionBar is introduced in API Level 13).

But I want to use ActionBar feature in projects for Froyo. Where can I find libraries which add ActionBar feature for Froyo?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)